# The new created terminal can not find the file use which in Mac

Tags: terminal, mysql

After I installed the mysql in my Mac, it locate in the:

```
/usr/local/mysql
```

And after I use `export` add the PATH to the $PATH, I can use `which mysql_config` find it:

```
aircraftdeMacBook-Pro:/ ldl$ which mysql_config
/usr/local/mysql/bin//mysql_config
```

But however when I use <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> create a new Terminal, in it can not searched the `mysql_config` now:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Add this `export $PATH` to the `~/.bash_profile` file. This file is "executed" every time new Terminal window/tab is opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you modify the PATH variable in a Terminal session by exporting it (e.g. `export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"` it will be expired in the next session.

So either edit the file ~/.bash_profile or edit /private/etc/paths if you need this PATH for other users also.

In ~/.bash_profile add the line:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

In /private/etc/paths add the line

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Close your current Terminal session, launch a new one to enable the new PATH and check the result:

```
echo $PATH
which mysql_config
```

Comment: If there is diffrence between `export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"` and `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin"`

Comment: @aircraft The first occurrence of a file x in the path will be executed or found with `which`. If you would have an old version of mysql_config in e.g /usr/bin it would be executed in the second case but not your new mysql_config. It's the other way round in the first case: the file mysql_config in /usr/local/mysql/bin/ would be executed preferably and the file /usr/bin/mysql_config would be ignored.